# Link issue: A custom class (QQuickFlow alike) derived from QQuickBasePositioner

Tags: c++, qt5, qtquick2, derived-class

I created a custom class called `QQuickFlexFlow`, basically, a copy from `QQuickFlow`, but the compiler gives the following errors:

> ```
> release/flexflow.o:flexflow.cpp:(.text+0x7b0): undefined reference to
> `QQuickBasePositioner::PositionedItem::updatePadding(double, double,
> double, double)'
> release/flexflow.o:flexflow.cpp:(.text$_ZN27QQuickBasePositionerPrivate13itemDestroyedEP10QQuickItem[__ZN27QQuickBasePositionerPrivate13itemDestroyedEP10QQuickItem]+0x15): undefined reference to
> `QQuickBasePositioner::PositionedItem::PositionedItem(QQuickItem*)'
> E:/Qt/Qt5.6.2/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> release/flexflow.o: bad reloc address 0x15 in section
>  `.text$_ZN27QQuickBasePositionerPrivate13itemDestroyedEP10QQuickItem[__ZN27QQuickBasePositionerPrivate13itemDestroyedEP10QQuickItem]'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status mingw32-make[2]: ***
> [release\myapp.exe] Error 1
> ```

Which lib file should be linked? How to find out the appropriate lib file? Any tip will be helpful. Thanks!

And if the symbols are not exported at all, how to fix these issues (the Qt source code is available)?

Comment: Two commands, `objdump` and `nm` are used to extract symbols defined in shared libraries, and I used them countless times to figure out which library I need to link with. See their manual pages for more information.

Comment: I used the command "$ nm *.a | grep updatePadding", nothing found. And used "$ nm *.a | grep updateGeometry", a lot of matched symbols found. The missed symbols are not exported?